# QtWebkit and Flask to make native desktop app

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, qtwebkit

I'm new to python. I'm looking for new way to create desktop application by QtWebkit and Flask.

the idea is : rather than open Flask web app on user browser, run and open it on QtWebkit GUI.

I wrote the following code , but it seems wrong. when Flask start running the GUI will be hanged .

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "<a href='http://127.0.0.1:5000/test'>AA</a><br />Hello World!"

@app.route('/test')
def test():
    return 'test'

pyqt = QApplication(sys.argv)

web = QWebView()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    web.load(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:5000/"))
    web.show()
    app.run()
    sys.exit(pyqt.exec_())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the GUI to be active and responsive its main loop has to run. The main loop is executed with the `exec_()` call. The control flow never reaches this call in your example because `app.run()` runs the Flask server and does not return.

GUIs usually need to run in the main thread so you better start the web application server in its own thread:

```
from threading import Thread

# ...

app_thread = Thread(target=app.run)
app_thread.daemon = True
app_thread.start()

# ...
```

The `start()` method starts a new thread that runs the server asynchronously and returns to the caller.

Comment: thanks, would you tell how to end `app.run()` thread when application closed or end ?

Comment: It should automatically stop when the process ends.

Comment: It should but it doesn't. I use another way : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114221/python-gui-by-qtwebkit-and-flask